# MS Outlook Task REST API '% Complete' field

Tags: rest, outlook-restapi

The Outlook Task UI has a field '% Complete' which is stored to a precision of 1 decimal place.

[image]

However, unless I am missing something, the properties accessible in the API (both REST and Graph [beta] ) don't seem to support this field.

For a completed Task, you can get/set the following properties:

- completedDateTime
- status (notStarted, inProgress, completed, waitingOnOthers, deferred)

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask

However, a task that is 'inProgress' doesn't seem to enable a '% Complete' qualifier.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find the solution for this? I'm having the same problem, and trying to research on how to retrieve it.

What I did as a work around is to manually set the percentage by checking the status of the tasks. If its completed I set it to 100%, if its not started I set it to 0% but I still need the actual ones if it's set to In Progress or other status.

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Sorry, no progress and my project priority shifted away from this.  Also, interesting that no-one from MSFT responded, although they have many people monitoring these forums.  My assumption is that the Task feature is moving out of Outlook/Exchange and into one of the newer tools like Planner & Teams, so there is no interest in plugging this gap.  There is a 'connector' for Planner that supports the '% complete' field; see more at:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/planner/